# Dialogflow inline editor ask for additional info

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, voice-recognition

I am developing a google assistant app on Dialogflow.
And I have a intent that receives two entities: @name and @age
Using the fulfillment throught the inline editor I verify if the @age is below 18.
In that case I need to ask for additional info, I need to ask the name of the person responsible for the child.

I looked around the internet, including the fulfillment samples at https://dialogflow.com/docs/samples

I believe it would look something like this:

```
let conv = agent.conv();
conv.ask('As your age is under 18 I need the name of the person responsible for you:');

//Some code to retrieve user input into a variable

agent.add(conv);
```

But I was unable to find how to do it.

Can someone help me to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are handling an Intent, there is no way to "wait for" the user to respond to your question. Instead, you need to handle user input this way:

- You send a response back from your Intent.
- The user replies with something they say.
- You handle this new user statement through an Intent.

Intents always represent the user taking some action - usually saying something.

So one approach would be to create a new Intent that accepts the user's response. But somehow you need to distinguish this response from the initial Intent that captured the person's name.

One way to do this would be, in the case you ask the question about who the responsible adult is, is to also set a [Context](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts). Then you can have a different Intent be triggered only when that Context is set and handle this new Intent to get the name of the adult.

Comment: I will read this documentation and implement it like you said. Thank you!